# "ObjectNotFoundException" The type caught or thrown must be derived from system.exception

Tags: entity-framework-4

Using Entity Framework on .Net 4
Here is my code:

```
        using (frfcourEntities frf = new frfcourEntities())
        {
            EntityKey routehdrId = new EntityKey("frfcourEntities.Routehdrs", "Refno", "xxx");
            try{
                var routehdr = frf.GetObjectByKey(routehdrId);
                frf.DeleteObject(routehdr);
                frf.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch(System.Data.ObjectNotFoundException)
            {}
        }
```

The line:

```
catch(System.Data.ObjectNotFoundException)
```

will not compile. It reports

```
The type caught or thrown must be derived from System.Exeception.
```

But ObjectNotFoundException is what the EF GetObjectByKey method throws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an assembly reference to System.Data. Without it "using System.Data" works but it doesn't resolve DataException.